# ShowModal only if form input exists

Tags: jquery

I have this attribute assignment:

```
$("form")
    .attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data")
    .attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data")
    .attr("onsubmit", "startProgressBar();showModal();");
```

What I want to do, is NOT do the showModal() if
`$("form").find("input.form-control").length == 0`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a conditional, like so:

```
//Default submit actions
var submitActions = "startProgressBar();";

//Add showModal(); if there's an input
if ($("form input.form-control").length) {
    submitActions += "showModal();";
}

$("form")
    .attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data")
    .attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data")
    .attr("onsubmit", submitActions);
```

I've removed `find`, as I believe just having a more specific selector is more efficient. As far as methodology, I've created a string variable to store the `onsubmit` events. If there's an input, `showModal();` is added to the events. We then use that in our `.attr`.

Answer (score 0):

Add it under condition:

```
var $form = $("form");
$form
    .attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data")
    .attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
if ($form.find("input.form-control").length == 0){
    $form.attr("onsubmit", "startProgressBar();");
} else {
    $form.attr("onsubmit", "startProgressBar();showModal();");
}
```

Comment: This actually worked, too  `.attr("onsubmit", "startProgressBar();if($('input.form-control').length){showModal();}");`

Comment: If you're going to re-use a selector, as `$("form")` in this case, I suggest setting it to a variable... `var $form = $("form");`. Each time you use a selector, it forces jQuery to go look it up again. Storing it once prevents this.

Comment: Yes it would work, but it will test its existence on each submit. (Which might not be a real problem though). @Santi +1